# (C++/win32) Hide a window so that the user cannot alt-tab or switch to it

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface, window, alt-tab

I'm currently using `ShowWindow( hwnd, SW_HIDE )`, but <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> still seems to be able to switch to it after it's hidden.

Is there a way to completely hide a window without destroying it?

EDIT: I should add that using the `WS_EX_TOOLBOX` style doesn't help. With enough <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> and `ShowWindow(SW_SHOW)`, some strange things happen.

Comment: SW_HIDE should work. Are you sure your message gets delivered? Is your main GUI thread still pumping messages after your call SW_HIDE?

Comment: @IvanShcherbakov Yes the messages are getting delivered...Also, I tried handling WM_ACTIVATE instead, but Alt-Tab just stops sending WM_ACTIVATE messages after a few Alt-Tabs.

Comment: How exactly are you handling them? If you start returning DefWindowProc() for every message, just for a simple experiment, will SW_HIDE work as intended?

Comment: @IvanShcherbakov I return DefWindowProc() for every message (I don't `return 0`, I just `break;` and `return DefWindowProc()` at the end). The SW_HIDE does work but it seems that it cannot evade Alt-Tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to hide window 
I have try this code and hidden window will be not appear while you pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>  [ I am using win-xp]
To show window press <kbd>Tab</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>

```
HWND hwnd_win = GetForegroundWindow();
ShowWindow(hwnd_win,SW_HIDE);
while(1)
{
    Sleep(1000);
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE|VK_TAB ))
        break;
}   
ShowWindow(hwnd_win,SW_SHOW);
```

Comment: =/ I'm using Windows 7 and can confirm that `SW_HIDE` does not fully evade Alt+Tab if you Alt+Tab enough times.

Comment: Ok I am working with Win-XP and it is working fine..
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx